# Estimate for the root of a polynomial-like expression

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polynomials, roots

I'm interest in finding the bound (upper and lower) of the positive root ($x>0$) of the following expression:
$$ F(x) := A(p-1)x^{p+1} + A(p+1)x^p - (p-1)x - \frac{p-1}{p+1},$$
where $A \ge 1$ and $p \ge 2$ are given real numbers.  Note that $p$ may not be an integer.

I looked at the following:

$$F(0) = -\frac{p-1}{p+1} < 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) = \infty$$
to conclude that there is a positive root at $x = x_0$.  The root is also unique since $F(x)$ is convex for all positive $x$.

Is there anyway to find the estimate of $x_0$ (asymptotic form is fine, upper bound is preferred) in terms of $p$ and $A$?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that for $x=1$ you have
$$F(1)=2Ap-(p-1)-\frac{p-1}{p+1}\geq\frac{p^2+p+2}{p+1}>0,$$
so certainly $x<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that

$$F(1)=2Ap-(p-1)-\frac{p-1}{p+1}=\frac{(2A-1)(p+1)p+2}{p+1}>0$$

which tells us the root is in the interval $(0,1)$.

The first derivative is given by

$$F'(x)=A(p^2-1)x^p+A(p^2+p)x^{p-1}-(p-1)$$

while the second derivative is given by

$$F''(x)=A(p^3-p)(x+1)x^{p-2}\ge0$$

which proves this is convex on $[0,\infty)$.

This proves secant lines will overestimate between the two intersections while tangent lines will always underestimate. Using the secant line intersecting at $x=0$ and $x=1$ and the tangent line at $x=1$ gives us

$$S(x)=[2Ap-(p-1)]x-\frac{p-1}{p+1}$$

$$T(x)=[A(2p^2+p-1)-(p-1)](x-1)+2Ap-(p-1)-\frac{p-1}{p+1}$$

$$S(x)\le F(x)\le T(x)\tag{$\forall x\in[0,1]$}$$

$S$ and $T$ have roots at

$$x_S=\frac{p-1}{(p+1)[2Ap-(p-1)]}$$

$$x_T=1-\frac{(2A-1)(p+1)p+2}{(p+1)[A(2p^2+p-1)-(p-1)]}$$

respectively. This bounds the actual root in the interval $(x_S,x_T)$, and repeating this process can give increasingly tighter bounds, though after this first iteration they are messy due to the exponents.

---

One can further extend the above by noting that the third derivative is positive. By Taylor's theorem, the quadratic

$$T_2(x)=T(x)+\frac12F''(1)(x-1)^2$$

satisfies $T_2(x)\ge F(x)$ for $x\le1$, allowing us to improve the lower bound without involving complicated exponents.

If one is willing to drop bounds and go for approximations in general, then a pseudo-secant-Taylor quadratic can be formed from

$$S_2(x)=T(x)+\alpha(x-1)^2$$

where $\alpha$ is such that $F(0)=S_2(0)$. This avoids using the second derivative and may prove to be a useful approximation of the root.